# How can I configure my docker tests to run on Travis CI correctly?

Tags: python, docker, unix, docker-compose, travis-ci

I have different `Dockerfile`s for both my frontend (Vuejs) and backend (django), along with two `docker-compose` files to run their development servers and testing stages. They run perfectly fine on my machine. They however error out when running a testing build on Travis-CI.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=uni69204passwd
      - POSTGRES_DB=uni-db
  backend:
    build: ./backend/
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - database
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend/
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    depends_on:
      - database
      - backend

volumes:
  backend:
  frontend:
  postgres_data:
```

`docker-compose.test.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:3.4.0"
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://frontend:3000
    working_dir: /testing
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/testing
    entrypoint: "sh -c 'sleep 15; ./wait-for-it.sh frontend:3000 --strict -- cypress run'"

volumes:
  cypress:
```

`.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 14.8.0
services:
  - docker
before_script:
  - docker-compose run frontend sh -c "npm install"
script:
  - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml up --abort-on-container-exit
  - docker-compose run --entrypoint "" backend pytest --flake8

notifications:
  email: false
```

`frontend/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

EXPOSE 3000

# Use `node` user that `node:lts-alpine` provides
RUN mkdir -p /app && chown -R node /app

USER node

WORKDIR /app
```

`backend/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

EXPOSE 8000

# install psycopg2, pillow and argon2_cffi dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev

RUN mkdir -p /app && adduser -D -h /app -u 1000 python && chown -R python /app

WORKDIR /app

ENV SECRET_KEY=e75)h*54&*^&(secret-keyd+=^%mb0n \
    SQL_USER=user \
    SQL_PASSWORD=uni69204passwd \
    SQL_HOST=database \
    SQL_PORT=5432 \
    SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql \
    SQL_DATABASE=uni-db \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

USER python

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Here's the error I get during the test build:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2020-09-15T18_05_28_175Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend `Dockerfile`, when you're `chown`ing the `/app` directory after creating it, try adding a `:` after the username.

i.e.

```
RUN mkdir -p /app && chown -R node: /app
```

This will chown of /app to both user and group `node`.

Also could be that you're overwriting it in your docker-compose file with the `- ./frontend:/app` volume definition.